# how to select a path from gallery in android using spinner view

Tags: android

I am making an application where user will select an image path from his android phone and then he can upload this image via any device such as Bluetooth..
for this i have to use services to upload the image and when image is uploaded i have to show it using notification bar
As I am new to android please give me full code for this

Thanks 
Nipa

Comment: no can have time to create ur whole app.try to start coding then ask here when u get any problems...

Comment: at least give me hint on how to proceed..